# How to represent multi-way data associations

Tags: c++, data-structures

I may be having a bad day because this feels so basic, but I can't settle on an approach that feels right. I have this as part of a larger class,

```
std::vector<std::tuple<A, B, C>> m_data;

std::optional<const C&> get_C_from_A(const A&);
std::optional<const C&> get_C_from_B(const B&);
```

Because they are associations, maps feel natural, but in this case I'd need multiple maps (A->C and B->C) and keeping the data consistent feels like it might get pretty gross. A simple array cleans that up.

Is there a name for what I'm doing, and am I doing it in a reasonable way and is there perhaps a better programming facility to express these relationships?

Comment: [`boost::multi_index`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html)?

Comment: @StoryTeller - I'm in a project that has it's own standard library and idioms (WebKit) and I can't bring in boost, so was hoping for something a bit simpler to implement than this (and I'm not good enough to understand boost code)

Comment: why not std::multimap ?

Comment: @CT - Then if you don't mind a bit of indirection, perhaps a pair of `std::map<?, std::shared_ptr<C>>`?

Comment: @StPiere is like the opposite of a multimap

Comment: @StoryTeller i'm not sure that's conceptually clearer than the flat array of tuples, but i feel I miss your insight

Comment: It's two mappings, but the value being mapped to is shared (as the library type name implies). So it spares you the part you deemed "gross".

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, but with a vector i have clear memory semantics, less memory footprint (not storing pointers & C values twice and not wrapping in shared ptrs)

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too. Those clear memory semantics are what's keeping you away from having two indices. Instead of asking open ended questions, I suggest you take the time to actually describe **all** of your constraints.